# How to align sth in a div to bottom?

Tags: html, css

There is `h1`,`p`,`a` in a `div`, I want `h1` in the top of the `div`, and `a` in the bottom of the `div`, and `p` in the middle no matter the height of `p`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffq4m2j4/)

Here is source:

html

```
<div class="box">    
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>text <br>line2<br>line3</p>
    <a href="#">bottom</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>text <br>line2</p>
    <a href="#">bottom</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 1px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.box div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.box p {
  padding: 0;
  margin-right:5px;
  text-wrap:normal;
}
.box a {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following solution works for you:

```css
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 1px;
    position: relative;
}
.box div {
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
}
.box h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.box p {
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
.box a {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">    
    <div>
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>text <br>line2<br>line3</p>
      <a href="#">bottom</a>
    </div><div>
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <p>text <br>line2</p>
      <a href="#">bottom</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ffq4m2j4/1/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to do that without `height: 100%` ?

Comment: as per my knowledge no.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to add ***relative*** position for parent div and ***absolute*** for children you want to put on bottom.

```
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 1px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position :relative;
}

a{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Now you can put everything on bottom or on top of parent div with no problems...